# How to add liquid file URL in theme using assets API shopify theme

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node, shopify-api

Hey anyone can help me how do i add liquid file using URL. I am trying this but this is not working

```
let add_assets_asset = {
  "asset": {
    "key": "layout/alternate.liquid",
    "src": "https://digitalcodingkloud.000webhostapp.com/new.liquid"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `value` attribute and pass the content itself (not URLs).

```
let add_assets_asset = {
  "asset": {
    "key": "layout/alternate.liquid",
    "value": "Your liquid content goes here..."
  }
};
```

`src` attribute can only be used to pass image URLs, not liquid files.